# Simulink, calling a function from a statemachine on top level

Tags: function, matlab, simulink, subsystem

My situation in an example:
I have a function block which is called Heute() and it is locatet in an an subsystem "test" and within that subsystem in the subsystem "t2"[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXCB7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DND7F.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyP2h.jpg)

If i now want to call the function from a statmachine which is at the same level as the "test" subsystem i receive the error: Undefined function or variable 'test.t2.Heute'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUniU.jpg)

But if i put the statemachine in the subsystem "test" on the same level as the subsystem "t2" it works [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LtUD.jpg)

Thanks for your help

I adjsustet the function call in the statemachine to test.t2.Heute() but that does not work

i tried to use function caller blocks but it doesnt seem to work eiter